# How do I check if int[] contains only certain numbers?

Tags: c#, arrays, error-checking

I need to check that an int[] contains only certain values (in this case 0s & 1s) and throw an exception if it doesn't.

Is there a more efficient way to do it than either of the following solutions?

Simple (but O(n)):

```
for(int n = 0; n < myArray.Length; n++)
    if(!(myArray[n] == 0 || myArray[n] == 1))
        throw new Exception("Array contains invalid values");
```

Using Where():

```
if(myArray.Where(n => !(n==1 || n==0)).ToArray().Length > 0)
    throw new Exception("Array contains invalid values");
```

Comment: Do you want to stop processing when  you encounter an invalid value, or do you want to validate the entire collection ?

Comment: Under the constraints, your `for` loop is the best you can get. Looks like you think LINQ can do "magic" because you didn't say O(N) for the "using Where()"

Comment: Also, I can't help thinking of [this](http://i.imgur.com/dAEp7Wu.jpg?1)

Comment: No need to validate the entire array as any single error is a fail.
As for Where(), I wasn't sure if it would've made some subtle under-the-hood differences or not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't check an array without iterating through it. So `O(n)` is the best you are going to get. The other solution would be to control loading the array and throw an exception when somebody tries to put a value that isn't `0` or `1` in it. Another solution might be to use a `bool[]` which only has two possible values anyway, but would require some conversion if you actually need numbers. (Note: if you needed more than two values, it might make sense to look at an `enum`, especially if those values are supposed to represent *something*)

Also, `Where` is not the best solution here because you are forced to check the whole array (no early exit). Use `Any` instead (but it's still doing basically what your for loop is doing - best case `O(1)`, worse `O(n)` average `O(n)`).

```
if (myArray.Any(a => a != 0 && a != 1))
{
     // ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer towards Any()
Gonna have to stick with ints, as the rest of the program relies on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`Array.TrueForAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2kykt9x.aspx):

```
if (!Array.TrueForAll(myArray, n => n == 0 || n == 1))
     throw new Exception("Array contains invalid values");
```

Comment: Per MSDN Documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdxe4x4w(v=vs.110).aspx This is still O(n), although it's at least a little cleaner anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Here is research blog post according to your question
http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000682.html

tested on

```
int[] data = new int[100000000];
```

if you are really interested in performance you shouldn't use Any() for sure )))))

so as far you need to search for couple values in array the unswer is - for loop search or foreach (in your case of int[] compiled into the CIL as for loop)  is the best options for you

```
foreach loop search:            39 ms
for loop search:                39 ms
Contains() method search:       56 ms
Any() method search:            446 ms
IndexOf() method search:        57 ms
```

Comment: `you shouldn't use Any() for sure`, if you don't have a 100 million element array, I wouldn't worry about it unless it is revealed to be an *actual bottleneck* in your *actual code*.

Comment: @MattBurland you are right, but I wrote "if you are really interested in performance ...", also if you take a look at the Any() compiled into the CIL you'll see how Any() differs from the for loop and test numbers show this difference on practice